# How reduce draw call in this sence? URP SRP Batcher

Tags: unity-game-engine, urp

Unity2021.3.10f1, URP, SRP Batcher on

I created a 10x10x10 cube matrix in the sence.
The cube is a prefab. It 1:1:1 default size, with a SRP Batcher compatible shader.

Now 5000+ Batches in runtime. How can I reduce the batches?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: SRP batcher is for Scriptable Render pipeline, isn't that much compatible with URP. Have you tried turning it off?

Comment: Yep, I tried.  Batches down to 50~60.  Same FPS.    Actually, I wanna optimize the FPS of this scene.  Alots of same cube, draw them spent too much CPU.

Comment: Have you tried GPU instancing?

Comment: Thank you. I have tried GPU Instantce.  That cubes need box collider. I dont know how to add collisions.  I'll searching for it.

Comment: Try **[GpuInstancingForGameObjects.cs](https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/df4a36ff2ad89078258fd653c422a021)** ([drag&drop](https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/df4a36ff2ad89078258fd653c422a021?permalink_comment_id=4165140#gistcomment-4165140) and all of this is gpu instanced)

Comment: Wow! I really need this. Thanks~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: workflow]
source: https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/df4a36ff2ad89078258fd653c422a021

```
// scr* https://gist.github.com/andrew-raphael-lukasik/df4a36ff2ad89078258fd653c422a021
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GpuInstancingForGameObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Camera _camera = null;
    [SerializeField] MeshRenderer[] _meshRenderers = new MeshRenderer[0];
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Prefer "true" ☑ as "false" ☐ require updates every frame.
    /// It is a good idea to keep lists of still and moving mesh renderers in a separate components.
    /// </summary>
    public bool meshesAreStill = true;

    Dictionary<(Mesh mesh,Material material),(List<Transform> transforms,Bounds aabb)> _sources = new Dictionary<(Mesh,Material),(List<Transform>,Bounds)>();
    Dictionary<(Mesh mesh,Material material),(Matrix4x4[] matrices,Bounds aabb)> _batches = new Dictionary<(Mesh,Material),(Matrix4x4[],Bounds)>();
    Dictionary<int,Stack<Matrix4x4[]>> _freeMatrices = new Dictionary<int,Stack<Matrix4x4[]>>();
    Plane[] _frustum = new Plane[6];
    
    void Start ()
    {
        Initialize();
        UpdateMatrices();

        if( _camera==null ) _camera = Camera.main;
        if( _camera==null )
        {
            Debug.LogError( "no camera, can't continue" , this );
            enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if( !meshesAreStill ) UpdateMatrices();

        GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes( _camera , _frustum );
        foreach( var batch in _batches )
        {
            var meshMaterialPair = batch.Key;
            var matricesAabbPair = batch.Value;
            var aabb = matricesAabbPair.aabb;
            if( GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(_frustum,aabb) )
            {
                Graphics.DrawMeshInstanced(
                    mesh:           meshMaterialPair.mesh ,
                    submeshIndex:   0 ,
                    material:       meshMaterialPair.material ,
                    matrices:       matricesAabbPair.matrices
                );
            }
        }
    }

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    // void OnDrawGizmosSelected ()
    void OnDrawGizmos ()
    {
        Initialize();

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        foreach( var source in _sources )
        {
            var transformsAabbPair = source.Value;
            var aabb = transformsAabbPair.aabb;
            Gizmos.DrawWireCube( aabb.center , aabb.size );
            
            if( Application.isPlaying && !GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(_frustum,aabb) )
                UnityEditor.Handles.Label( aabb.center , "(out of camera view)" );
        }
    }
    #endif

    void Initialize ()
    {
        _sources.Clear();
        foreach( var meshRenderer in _meshRenderers )
        {
            if( meshRenderer==null ) continue;
            var meshFilter = meshRenderer.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            if( meshFilter==null ) continue;
            var mesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;
            if( mesh==null ) continue;
            foreach( var material in meshRenderer.sharedMaterials )
            {
                if( !material.enableInstancing && Application.isPlaying )
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning($"\"{material.name}\" material won't be rendered as it's <b>GPU Instancing</b> is not enabled",meshRenderer);
                    continue;
                }
                if( material==null ) continue;
                var aabb = meshRenderer.bounds;
                var meshMaterialPair = ( mesh , material );
                if( _sources.ContainsKey( meshMaterialPair ) )
                {
                    var transforms = _sources[meshMaterialPair].transforms;
                    transforms.Add( meshRenderer.transform );

                    var newAabb = _sources[meshMaterialPair].aabb;
                    newAabb.Encapsulate( aabb );

                    _sources[meshMaterialPair] = ( transforms , newAabb );
                }
                else
                {
                    _sources.Add( meshMaterialPair , ( new List<Transform>(){ meshRenderer.transform } , aabb ) );
                }
            }
            if( Application.isPlaying )
                meshRenderer.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    void UpdateMatrices ()
    {
        foreach( var batch in _batches )
        {
            var matricesAabbPair = batch.Value;
            var matrices = matricesAabbPair.matrices;
            if( _freeMatrices.ContainsKey( matrices.Length ) )
            {
                _freeMatrices[matrices.Length].Push( matrices );
            }
            else
            {
                var stack = new Stack<Matrix4x4[]>();
                stack.Push( matrices );
                _freeMatrices.Add( matrices.Length , stack );
            }
        }
        _batches.Clear();

        foreach( var source in _sources )
        {
            var meshMaterialPair = source.Key;
            var transformsAabbPair = source.Value;
            var transforms = transformsAabbPair.transforms;
            
            int numTransforms = transforms.Count;
            Matrix4x4[] matrices = null;
            if( _freeMatrices.ContainsKey(numTransforms) && _freeMatrices[numTransforms].Count!=0 )
            {
                matrices = _freeMatrices[numTransforms].Pop();
            }
            else matrices = new Matrix4x4[ numTransforms ];

            for( int i=0 ; i<numTransforms ; i++ )
                matrices[i] = transforms[i].localToWorldMatrix;
            _batches.Add( meshMaterialPair , ( matrices , transformsAabbPair.aabb ) );
        }
    }

}
```

This solution provides AABB frustum culling - it is not enough to optimize your voxels-like case but a starting point. If you consider these boxes to represent voxels then your next step would be to implement a voxel occlusion culling here (to hide boxes that are inside this shape).

[image]